OpenFOAM - coded error to obtain surface normal gradient
I created the code below and managed to compile it successfully in OpenFOAM 11. However, there is no result coming out, the directories are being generated, but the information about the face normals is not being written. What could I be doing wrong? I actually only want the normal on the wall faces.
computeNormals
{
   libs ("libutilityFunctionObjects.so");
   type coded; 
   redirectType    computeNormals; 
   writeControl    timeStep; //outputTime; 
       
   code 
   #{
       //const surfaceVectorField& normals = mesh().Sf();
       //normals.write();
    
       //const vectorField& Sfp = mesh_.Sf().boundaryField()[patchi];
       //const scalarField& magSfp = mesh_.magSf().boundaryField()[patchi];
    
       const vectorField& Sfp = mesh().Sf();
       const scalarField& magSfp = mesh().magSf();
    
       Sfp.write();
       magSfp.write();        
   #};
}

